# What is alternative of cacheable="false"

Tags: magento2, layout, cache, product-list

I am developing a module i which i override the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php by preferece  and list.phtml by catalog_category_view.xml layout.

Correct product listing data is come when i run the cache clean command. When I write cacheable="false" then product listing show correct data but i don't want to use cacheable="false" because it wil error on marketplace.

I don't understand why need cache clean on every refresh if i don't use cacheable false. what is alternative of cacheable="false".

I override the Toolbar.php by preference

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />


public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $Resource = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $helper = $objectManager->get('\Vendor\Module\Helper\Data');

    $this->_collection = $collection;
    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());

    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }

    if($moduleEnable = $helper->getConfigModuleEnabled()){

        $coordinates = $helper->getlatlogSession();
        $customerCoordinates = explode(',', $coordinates);
        $customerLat = $customerCoordinates[0];
        $customerLang = $customerCoordinates[1];

        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            switch ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
                case 'distance':
                    $data = [];
                    foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
                        $sku = $value->getData('sku');
                        $sourceCoordinates = $helper->getSourceLatLang($sku);
                        if (count($sourceCoordinates) > 1) {
                            $sourceCoordinates = $this->getNearestfromArray($sourceCoordinates, $customerLat, $customerLang, $helper);
                        }
                        foreach($sourceCoordinates as $item){
                            $sourceLat = $item['latitude'];
                            $sourceLang = $item['longitude'];
                            $distance = $helper->calculateDistance($customerLat, $customerLang, $sourceLat, $sourceLang);
                            $data[$value->getData('entity_id')] = [$distance, $value->getData('price')];
                        }
                    }
                    asort($data);
                    $ids = implode(',', array_keys($data));
                    $logger->info('ids ' .$ids);
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->order(array(new \Zend_Db_Expr("FIELD(e.entity_id, " . $ids . ")")));
                    // $helper->flushCache();
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());

                    break;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    else{
       $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}
```

I craeted a custom sortby option Distance and $ids variable give me sorted product id's that is working fine,but also i created a popup for pincode through default.xml

```
<head>
  <link src="Vendor_Module::js/location.js"/>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-block-name" template="Vendor_Module::popup.phtml" ifconfig="nearbyproducts/general/enable" />
    </referenceContainer>

</body>
```

[image]

When I enter the pincode page is reload by JS but request is not come in the setCollection method because maybe products are coming from cache. When I added cacheable false in default.xml it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best alternative of `cacheable="false"` is to use private content.

You can use private content, visit this link -> [CLICK HERE](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/cache/page/private-content/)

This is the Magento way to use private content.

And for best example you can go through this blog
[CLICK HERE](https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-use-private-content-or-sections-in-magento-2/)

Comment: I applied the sorting on product collection in Toolbar.php and collection is sort when i clean cache. can you please suggest me how can i use section for this?

Comment: Can you please add your code in question for more clarification?

Comment: I have added code for more clarification, can you please provide me solution?